# Getting 404 Error while requesting the controller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting 404 error when I try to contact the Controller.

Please find the information below,

My addslum.blade.php along with the script

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                {{ Form::open()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for=""> District</label>
                    <select name="district_option" id="district_option" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District --------</option>
                        @foreach ($districts as $key => $district)
                        <option value="{{$district->id}}">{{$district->district_name}}</option>

                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for=""> Municipality</label>
                    <select name="municipal_option" id="municipal_option" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                </div>
                {{Form::close()}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



<script>
    $('#district_option').on('change',function(e){
console.log(e);
var municipal_id = e.target.value;
var BASEURL = "{!! url('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/') !!};";
console.log(municipal_id);
$.get( BASEURL + 'districtview?municipal_id=' + municipal_id, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#municipal_option').empty();
    $('#municipal_option').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District First--------</option>');
 $.each(data,function(index, municipalObj){
    $('#municipal_option').append('<option value="'+ municipalObj.id +'"> '+ municipalObj.municipal_name +' </option>');


        })
        });
        }); 

</script>
```

web.php -

```
    Route::get('/addslum', 'newSlumController@listSlums');
Route::get('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/municipalview', 'newSlumController@municipalView');
```

Controller Code:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\District;
use App\Municipality;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class newSlumController extends Controller
{

public function listSlums()
{
    $districts = District::all();
      return view('admin.feature.addslum',compact('districts'));
}   

public function municipalView()
{
    $districts_id = Input::get('municipal_id');
    $municipalities = Municipality::where('district_id', '=', $districts_id )->get();
      return response()->json($municipalities) ;
}
```

I have checked the Chrome Network tool but I could see the the request is being generated to the url but I have didn't get any response.

Screenshot of the output 
[image]

My apologies if the question is repetitive. I am new to Laravel

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the request isn't calling a valid route, although it's difficult to tell for sure since your screenshot of the console is cut-off. Your available routes (web.php) are:

1. /addslum
2. /engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/municipalview

But in your screenshot it looks like the request is trying something like this:

/engineers-association-guntur/public/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature

Also, you have an error in your code (an extra semicolon) on the following line, which is adding an erroneous semicolon to the request URL:

```
var BASEURL = "{!! url('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/') !!};";
```

Should be:

```
var BASEURL = "{{ url('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/') }}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a request to this URL:

```
/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/districtview
```

but you have this in your web.php

```
Route::get('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/municipalview', 'newSlumController@municipalView');
```

They don't match up. municipalview <> districtview

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var BASEURL = "{!! url('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/') !!};";
```

to

```
var BASEURL = "{!! url('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/') !!}";
```

and route to

```
Route::get('/engineers-association-guntur/public/admin/feature/{type}', 'newSlumController@municipalView');
```

You can also use like this

```
{{route('alias_of_route', ['type => 'municipalview'])}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Bro, There was an extra semicolon in the URL field.